# Что делаю не так при добавлении своего шаблона для Ballon

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Всем привет. Помогите разобраться в вопросе добавления своего шаблона для балуна. Читал много документации и вопросов, но сталкиваюсь с проблемой, которую понять не могу. Точнее что делаю не так.

Есть карта. Метки добавляю из JSON с помощью **objectManager**

Выставляю **objectManager.objects.options.set('balloonLayout', 'MyBalloonLayout');**

При клике на метку не получаю открытый балун по кастомному шаблону, а получаю ошибку в консоле: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getModuleSync' of null*

```
    var MyBalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    '<h3>$[properties.balloonContentHeader]</h3>' +
    '<div>$[properties.balloonContentBody]</div>' +
    '<div> <a href="#" id="more">Подробнее</a></div>', {
      build: function() {
        MyBalloonContentLayout.superclass.build.call(this);
        $('#more').bind('click', this.onMoreClick);
      },
      clear: function() {
        $('#more').unbind('click', this.onMoreClick);
        MyBalloonContentLayout.superclass.clear.call(this);
      },
      onMoreClick: function() {
        alert('УРА');
      }
    }
  );

  // Добавляю опцию для балуна  
  objectManager.objects.options.set('balloonContentLayout', 'MyBalloonContentLayout');
```

Ссылка на пример кода: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mpyeRd?editors=1010

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый день. Ошибка в том, что у нас указана как значение опции не класс MyBalloonContentLayout, а строчка 'MyBalloonContentLayout'. API карт трактует строчку как название макета из набора стандартных. Стандартного макета под ключом 'MyBalloonContentLayout' нет - возникает ошибка (непонятная, да).
Вам надо всего лишь убрать кавычки при установке опции `objectManager.objects.options.set('balloonContentLayout', MyBalloonContentLayout);`

Comment: Спасибо большое, действительно так работает. И спасибо за объяснение.